# setAdapter from a String[] - nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

Eclipse, java - I'm trying do a setAdapter to create a listview from a String[] that it was generated in a class AsyncTask to create a sqlconnection. Can you help me to solve this problem?

My code:

```
        listaMontanha = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstmontanharussa);
    CriarMontanharussa();
    //listaMontanha.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, horariosMontanha));

}

public void CriarMontanharussa(){
    LerMontanha montanha = new LerMontanha();
    montanha.execute();
}

public class LerMontanha extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    int contador=0;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

      String response = null, codigo = null, hora, estado;
      int qt = 0;

      try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
            System.out.println("driver conectado");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.2:3306/savetime", "root", "root");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select cd_brinquedo from brinquedo where nm_brinquedo = 'montanha russa'");
            if (rs.next()) {
                codigo = rs.getString(1);
            }
            System.out.println("CODIGO= " +codigo );
            ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery("select hh_inicio_rodada from rodada where cd_brinquedo = " + codigo);
            while(rs1.next()) {

                hora = rs1.getString(1);
                System.out.println("hora= " + hora);
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery("select COUNT(*) from solucaoingressorodada where cd_brinquedo = " + codigo + " and hh_inicio_rodada = '" + hora+ "'");
                if (rs2.next()) {
                    qt = rs2.getInt(1);
                }
                System.out.println("qt= " + qt);
                if (qt<10){
                    estado="Disponível";
                } else {
                    estado ="Fila lotada";
                }
                horariosMontanha[contador] = hora + "         " + estado;
                contador= contador+1;
            }
            rs1.close();
            st.close();
            con.close();

      }
      catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.out.println("ERRO: " + e.toString());
      }

    return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resultado) {
        for (int i = 0; i < contador; i++){
            System.out.println(horariosMontanha[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

the logcat:

```
06-22 00:03:06.462: I/System.out(1196): driver conectado
06-22 00:03:07.261: I/System.out(1196): CODIGO= 1
06-22 00:03:07.371: I/System.out(1196): hora= 12:00:00
06-22 00:03:07.381: I/System.out(1196): qt= 1
06-22 00:03:07.391: I/System.out(1196): hora= 12:30:00
06-22 00:03:07.412: I/System.out(1196): qt= 0
06-22 00:03:07.431: I/System.out(1196): 12:00:00         Disponível
06-22 00:03:07.431: I/System.out(1196): 12:30:00         Disponível
06-22 00:03:07.511: D/AndroidRuntime(1196): Shutting down VM
    06-22 00:03:07.511: W/dalvikvm(1196): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196): java.lang.NullPointerException
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1156)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:602)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:415)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1850)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1102)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1275)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    06-22 00:03:07.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Don't set the adapter before you're sure it's in a valid state (and remains in a valid state). It seems that you want to create a view for an item that is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't take into account the asynchronous nature of `AsyncTask`. You call your `execute` method of the `LerMontanha montanha` object and set the adapter right away. The NullPointerException is happening because you try to use the array `horariosMontanha`, but when you're trying to use it, it still references `null`. I.e. the whole chunk of code in LerMontanha's `doInBackground` hasn't had a chance to update that variable.

Additionally, since you're updating `horariosMontanha` from two threads (the UI thread and the thread where `doInBackground` runs) you risk a lot of problems.

The effects of `AsyncTask`'s should happen in `onPostExecute` and once the array is ready, set the adapter.

Comment: Oh I see. So should I do all the act in onPostExecute of AsyncTask, including the setAdapter? Or how could I execute all the AsyncTask first and the setAdapter after?

Comment: One option would be to modify your AsyncTask such that it returns an array from doInBackground (and this array gets passed to onPostExecute) and in `onPostExecute` use this array to configure the adapter. Care must be taken that when onPostExecute runs, the activity is still in a valid state (i.e. don't set the adapter if the activity has been destroyed etc.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I did what you said and worked!